# Rolling groupby, but truncating each value at midnight

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have the following DataFrame:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({'ts': pl.date_range(datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 1, 10), '1h')})
df = df.with_columns(value=pl.Series(np.arange(len(df))))
```

```py
In [62]: df
Out[62]:
shape: (217, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ ts                  ┆ value │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0     │
│ 2020-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 2020-01-01 02:00:00 ┆ 2     │
│ 2020-01-01 03:00:00 ┆ 3     │
│ …                   ┆ …     │
│ 2020-01-09 21:00:00 ┆ 213   │
│ 2020-01-09 22:00:00 ┆ 214   │
│ 2020-01-09 23:00:00 ┆ 215   │
│ 2020-01-10 00:00:00 ┆ 216   │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

What I would like to get, for each row, is:

- consider all rows which are between 3 days before, and that same day at midnight
- calculate the mean

So, for example, for row `2020-01-09 23:00:00`, I would like to consider the rows where `ts` is greater or equal to `2020-01-06 00:00:00` and less than `2020-01-09 00:00:00` and take the mean of the `'value'` column.

Expected output:

```
shape: (217, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ ts                  ┆ value │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ null  │
│ 2020-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ null  │
│ 2020-01-01 02:00:00 ┆ null  │
│ 2020-01-01 03:00:00 ┆ null  │
│ …                   ┆ …     │
│ 2020-01-09 21:00:00 ┆ 155.5 │
│ 2020-01-09 22:00:00 ┆ 155.5 │
│ 2020-01-09 23:00:00 ┆ 155.5 │
│ 2020-01-10 00:00:00 ┆ 179.5 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

How I calculated the expected output:

```
df.filter(
    (pl.col("ts") >= datetime(2020, 1, 6)) & (pl.col("ts") < datetime(2020, 1, 9))
).mean()
df.filter(
    (pl.col("ts") >= datetime(2020, 1, 7)) & (pl.col("ts") < datetime(2020, 1, 10))
).mean()
```

Comment: you can replace `df = df.with_columns(value=pl.Series(np.arange(len(df))))` with `df = df.with_columns(value=pl.arange(0,pl.count()))` to avoid the np import and, more importantly, for future reference `pl.arange`, as you can see, takes expressions as input.

Comment: When you say the same day midnight, are you intending to create a range that the original value isn't in? In your example you say that `2020-01-09 23:00:00` should generate `[2020-01-06 00:00:00, 2020-01-09 00:00:00]` but then `2020-01-09 23:00:00` isn't within that range, rather it'd be in the range `[2020-01-06 00:00:00, 2020-01-10 00:00:00]`

Comment: "When you say the same day midnight, are you intending to create a range that the original value isn't in" that's right

Answer (score 1):

Oh, this seems to work:

```py
right = df.groupby_rolling('ts', period='3d', closed='left').agg(pl.col('value').mean()).filter(pl.col('ts').dt.hour()==0)
df.join(right, left_on=pl.col('ts').dt.truncate('1d'), right_on='ts')
```

```py
In [84]: df.join(right, left_on=pl.col('ts').dt.truncate('1d'), right_on='ts')
Out[84]:
shape: (217, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ ts                  ┆ value ┆ value_right │
│ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ f64         │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0     ┆ null        │
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1     ┆ null        │
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2     ┆ null        │
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 3     ┆ null        │
│ …                   ┆ …     ┆ …           │
│ 2020-01-09 00:00:00 ┆ 213   ┆ 155.5       │
│ 2020-01-09 00:00:00 ┆ 214   ┆ 155.5       │
│ 2020-01-09 00:00:00 ┆ 215   ┆ 155.5       │
│ 2020-01-10 00:00:00 ┆ 216   ┆ 179.5       │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: You could also use [`.rolling_mean`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_mean.html#polars-expr-rolling-mean) e.g. `df.with_columns(pl.col("value").rolling_mean(by="ts", window_size="3d")).with_columns(pl.col("value").first().over(pl.col("ts").dt.truncate("1d")))`